# ldapadd with automatic support for replace if entry already exists

Tags: ubuntu, backup, ldap, openldap

I've been doing some testing with `ldapadd` and `ldapmodify` and what I noticed is:

-`ldapadd` will fail if the entry already exists:

```
=> hdb_tool_entry_put: txn_aborted! DB_KEYEXIST: Key/data pair already exists (-30995)
ldapadd: could not add entry dn="mail=test1@example.org,ou=People,dc=example,dc=org" (line=1): txn_aborted! DB_KEYEXIST: Key/data pair already exists (-30995)
```

-`ldapmodify` will fail if the entry doesn't:

```
modifying entry "mail=test2@example.org,ou=People,dc=example,dc=org"
ldap_modify: No such object (32)
matched DN: ou=People,dc=example,dc=org
```

Therefore when restoring a backup on an existing database with some existing and some missing entries you can't just use either of these tools, you need to create a routine that:
-either deletes all the users that already exists in the database and are present in the backup and then import using `ldapadd`.
-or converts the backup ldif file to be ldapmodify-compatible (add or modify depending on whether the user exists) and use `ldapmodify`.

**Q: Isn't there a tool that would take care of that for you?**

Additional info: running `openldap 2.4.21` on `ubuntu server 10.04`

Comment: In case, the [assertion control](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/08/05/mastering-the-ldap-assertion-control/) can help with this sort of thing.

Comment: try ldapmodify with flags -ac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either give the `-a` flag to `ldapmodify` or put the line `changetype: add` into your LDIF data if you add an entry, and `changetype: modify` to modify the entry.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, change using `changetype: modify` you then have to create replace/add/remove statements for each attribute you're importing like `changetype: modify \N replace: cn \N cn: test etc..`